# VBA Macro - Sending PDF through outlook (Windows10) Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I really need some help here. I'm trying to export the active sheet in MS Excel as a PDF and have it save to the drive as well as Email it through outlook to several company different contacts. It seems to work with everyone who doesn't have Windows 10. I'm the only one with a Windows 10 PC. ActiveSheet is where i'm getting the error.
Below is the code that I've used but I keep getting a error message 1004

```
Name = Specific location
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Name, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas 
    _:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
    .Subject = 
    .To = 
    .CC =
    .Body = 
    .Attachments.Add Name 
    .send
End With
    MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", 64
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set Mail_Object = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The part that you are defining a mail item is not good, do sth like this, complete the code yourself:

```
Sub SendAttachment()
    Set olObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    With olObj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        .Subject = "mySubject"
        .To = "test@test.com"
        .CC = "test@test.com"
        .Body = "test"
        .Attachments.Add Name
        .send
    End With
End Sub
```

**PS:** It is always recommended to use explicit definitions (e.g. Dim sSubject as string)